# Migrating off applicationCache (Chrome M82)

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, html5-appcache

I am trying to complement existing offline appCache-based setup with a service worker for Chrome/Chromium(other browsers, namely Safari are still expected to use appCache).

Simplified [pseudo]code looks as follows:

```
<html manifest="offline.manifest">
    ...
     <script type="text/javascript">
         if (!window.applicationCache && navigator.serviceWorker && (/chrome/gi).test(navigator.appVersion)) {
             navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
         }
     </script>
    ...
</html>
```

My questions are:

- is there a way to figure out whether Chrome 82 will tolerate `<html manifest=offline.manifest>` attribute? (by the time of writing this question, people installing Chrome 82 Canary report appCache is still available)
- did anyone have a chance to use **sw-appcache-behavior** scripts in production?

Thanks.

UPD 08/05/20: AppCache removal has been moved to M85

Answer (score 0):

A few hints are available in the HTML spec [update](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/5505/files).

It looks like **manifest** attribute will still be honored but no actual caching is going to happen.

There seem to be a way for testing disabled appCache using [reverse] Origin Trial.
Details are available in blink-api-owners Google Group.

Despite **sw-appcache-behavior** [being suggested](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582750#c63) by Chromium maintainers, its readme section indicates that it is not intended to be used in Prod yet.

Comment: Chrome 84 beta features **AppCache web API and browser backend** which can be used for testing